# Holomorphic map containing $\mathbb{T}$ in its image?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following problem. Does there exists a holomorphic map $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}(\overline{\mathbb{D}})\cap\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D},\mathbb{D})$ such that $\mathbb{T}\subset\overline{\varphi(\mathbb{D})}$ but $\varphi(\mathbb{T})\neq\mathbb{T}$?

Remark: Note that the condition $\mathbb{T}\subset\overline{\varphi(\mathbb{D})}$ implies $\mathbb{T}\subset{\varphi(\mathbb{T})}.$

Comment: what is $\Bbb T$?

Comment: $\mathbb{T}$ stands for the unit circle centered at the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are holomorphic maps of the open unit disk which are continuius in the closed disk and such that the image of the boundary circle is the whole closed disk. I will supply a reference if this is what you are looking for.

See Theorem1 in http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1955-006-04/S0002-9939-1955-0072227-5/S0002-9939-1955-0072227-5.pdf for the reference.

Comment: Yes, That will answer the question. Please let me know the reference.

Comment: I have added the refence for the above. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this reference works, although this is not the oldest example.

Comment: Namely, reference [4] (Piranian, Titus and Young) in the linked paper seems to be the first example where the image is exactly a square (which is equivalent to the closed disk). Of course, all these papers build upon the construction of Salem and Zygmund (reference [5] in the link).

Comment: Yes, I also had a look on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

From the maximum modulus principle we have that if $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}(\overline{\mathbb{D}})\cap\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D},\mathbb{D})$ then $|φ(z)|\leq sup${$|φ(ζ)|:ζ\in \Bbb T$} for every $z\in \Bbb D$.

Then assume that there exists a function that does this job. 
Notice that $φ(\Bbb T)$ ,$\Bbb T$ are compact and so they have a distance. Let $x$ be the point in $φ(\Bbb T)$ that there we have the maximum distance from $\Bbb T$ (this means that $x\notin \Bbb T$). Then we have two cases:

$x$ is outside the circle or is inside the circle.

What can you say using the hint?

Comment: I'm not able to see how it'll help but thanks for your comment.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines: If we give unit parametrization to the circle and see the image loop under such a holomorphic map then this loop will not be a simple closed curve i.e. it has more than one bounded component.(why?) On the other hand I remember proving that a holomorphic map maps simple closed curves to simple closed curves.

Comment: So I'm working on this idea. What do you think about this idea?

Comment: Please see the answer above.

Comment: @Abelvikram, i wanted to show you that if $φ(\Bbb D)=\Bbb D$ the image $φ(\Bbb T)$ will be a something like a "subring" (let's say it will be ,to make it easier)$R(0,|x|,1)$ inside $\overline {\Bbb D}$. So you would want a curve,that is a set of measure zero,to have a continuous image with positive measure  $φ(\Bbb T)$. This can be done if $φ$ is almost differentiable everywhere,which is true here because $φ$ is not holomorphic in $\Bbb T$,only in $\Bbb D$. We want something like Peano curves. See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194472/a-curve-whose-image-has-positive-measure

Comment: Sorry but what is a subring? By your notation it seems you meant  an annulus, is it?

Comment: And if I have correctly understood you, then your claim is that any such map, if exists, must map $\mathbb{T}$ to a set of positive measure.

Comment: @Abelvikram, yes i mean an annulus and i don't know if every of these functions(curves) map a set of zero measure to a set of positive measure,but you can find some functions that do this,like the ones you see in the link.